# SQL Converting the date format in where clause

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, subquery, where-clause

When trying to connect two tables with a `where exists` clause, but the results don't get matched because of the time portions of my dates. The date in table 1 is `2020-09-01 00:00:00` and in table 2  is `2020-09-01 12:54:00`.

How do I format the date to match only based on `YYYY-MM-DD`?

```
SELECT * 
FROM  table1 a 
WHERE exists (
    SELECT '1' 
    FROM table2 b 
    WHERE a.company = b.company 
        AND a.emp =b.emp AND a.account_date = b.account_date
    )
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running. Date/time functions are highy database specific: mysql, sqlserver, oracle...?

Comment: If MySQL, you can use `DATE(a.account_date) = DATE(b.account_date)` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date. Though I'd suggest creating these as new columns additionally so they can take advantage of indexed values.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer? Does this help? Sorry, I am not quite technical.

Comment: "Oracle SQL Developer" is like telling us you drive a Sony because that's the brand printed on the dashboard stereo in your car.

Comment: LOL - I am actually a BA, I don't really know the difference. Will be happy to check it out if you have any good article to look in that case.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a desktop application for working with Oracle databases. So I guess your database is Oracle.

Comment: "Will be happy to check it out if you have any good article to look in that case."      Can't you simply ask the person who supports the database? You know, the guy you'd call if the database were to become unavailable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, you can use `trunc()`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1 a 
WHERE exists (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM table2 b 
    WHERE 
        a.company = b.company 
        AND a.emp = b.emp 
        AND trunc(a.account_date) = trunc(b.account_date)
)
```

It is often more efficient to express the date condition as follows:

```
WHERE
    ...
    AND b.account_date >= trunc(a.account_date) 
    AND b.account_date < trunc(a.account_date) + 1
```